# Does Cobalt support web components (e.g. do Polymer/lit-element work)?

Tags: polymer, web-component, cobalt

I know Cobalt has a list of supported features (https://cobalt.foo/development/reference/supported-features.html)

but the list of Web APIs seem small.  Does Polymer/lit-element work with Cobalt?

Answer (score 1):

Cobalt doesn't support custom elements, shadow DOM, or HTML templates. That said, I believe it's possible to make lit-html and lit-element to run on Cobalt with some creative polyfilling and source hacking.

Cobalt is known to run production apps written with Angular. If I'm not mistaken, I've seen a React prototype too.